# Windows 7 Ultimate - Evaluation Copy Expires Sept 1st 2011

Tags: windows-7, service-pack, windows-genuine-advantage

I have a genuine copy of Windows 7 from MSDN.  I get a message 'Evaluation Copy Expires Sept 1st 2011'

I read that this could be due to the Service Pack and not the OS.  So I uninstalled SP1, not a trivial task. then reapplied.

Great!  Good news, a result, it says build 7601 and no sign of Evaluation copy when I run Winver.

Then a few days later I applied more updates, which may, or may not be relevant, and get the same old message.  Evaluation Copy Expires...

I have read about some old 'stuff' lingering on the computer after I may have installed a pre-release / evaluation copy of SP1, but I cannot quite remember.

How can I cure this by Sept 1st?

Comment: To clarify, you installed using a Windows 7 RTM CD-key from MSDN?

Comment: And a possible silly question... You did activate?

Comment: I activated, even got a second key from MSDN.  I use PaintDesktopVersion and it says Evaluation Copy Build 7601

Comment: "I may have installed a pre-release / evaluation copy of SP1", sounds like the problem to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this forum credit should go to Moab.  It was a pre-release copy of SP1.

The solution was moderately interesting, I contacted Microsoft Support.  Filled in a form, admittedly I did have a Support number courtesy of the MVP program. Then a technician phoned me.

He collected info from Winver and a command-line licence program.  From this information he could diagnose: Genuine Licence, but dodgy SP1.

Told me to uninstall then reinstall an updated SP1.  I have to admit it, previously, I uninstalled and reinstalled the same pre-release SP1.  I feel silly now, but believe in telling all when I am among friends.

Comment: I have found in the past that MS is swift to fix license errors, which is a good thing.

Comment: Encourage Moab to write his comment as an answer, and then you can select that as the answer and award points appropriately. For the author there should be an option to promote a comment to a full answer.

Comment: Yes, you should definitely ask Moab if he'd like to write an answer. @music2myear [Often wanted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100729/add-a-feature-to-migrate-a-comment-into-an-answer/) but always rejected.

Comment: That is what I would like too, I am waiting for Moab to write an answer so that I can credit him. The ability to promote a comment would save us all time.